# How to send an HTML file content in REST API POST Request?

Tags: python, rest

I am trying to send an HTML file in a POST request in a python script.

```
html_source = """
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table class="sstable table-bordered inner-table">
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>T01</td>
        <td>Title 1</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>T02</td>
        <td>Title 2</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>T03</td>
        <td>Title 3</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body
        </html>
        """
auth_values = ('usernae','password')    
data = '{"name":"Some Widget","dashboardId":7,"type":"text","content":' '"' +html_source+ '"''}'
url = "company.com/api"
response = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=auth_values)

print ('Response Status:',response.status_code)
print ('Response Body:',response.content)
```

However, the request gives the following response:

```
('Response Status:', 200)
('Response Body:', '{"data":null,"errmsg":"Invalid json body","status":1007}')
```

Is it because of the way I am trying to pass the HTML string? I tried escaping the HTML but it still didn't work.

Is there a way I can point the `"content":` to a HTML file in my system?

Comment: You have to escape the double quotes from the HTML in the json.

Comment: @ANIL is the issue still in effect?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes

Comment: One more thing. The HTML code gets autogenerated for different conditions and sometimes the title fields can have double quotes around the title.